# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to 'NSURL'

Tags: swift

I'm working in swift and originally got the warning "'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding' was deprecated..." so I changed my code from

```
    let url = NSURL(string: (urlString as NSString).stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)
```

to

```
    var url = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

But now I'm getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSURL'.

```
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

My current code:

```
    private func handleTextFieldInterfaces(){
    autocompleteTextField.onTextChange = {[weak self] text in
        if !text.isEmpty{
            if self!.connection != nil{
                self!.connection!.cancel()
                self!.connection = nil
            }
            let urlString = "\(self!.baseURLString)?key=\(self!.googleMapsApiKey)&input=\(text)"
            //let url = NSURL(string: (urlString as NSString).stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)

           var url = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

            if url != nil{
                let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) //Error on this line
                self!.connection = NSURLConnection(request: urlRequest, delegate: self)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting it to NSURL see if it works

```
var url = NSURL(urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a different error now, but that solved the conversion one.