# How to convert userdefault value to URL?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve the URL from a UserDefault I saved previously, but parsing it to URL fails as states: "Cannot convert NSINLINEDATA to NSURL"

I've tried parsing it to String and then to URL but it only gives nil

**Set value**

```
    let videourl = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL
    if let videoURL = videourl{

       defaults.set(videourl,forKey: "LullabyURL")
    }
```

**Get value**

```
    let videoURL = defaults.value(forKey: "LullabyURL")
    let newStr = String(data: videoURL as! Data, encoding: .utf8)
    let vu = URL.init(string:newStr ?? "nil")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: vu!)
```

Comment: Are you sure videoUrl is storing in `UserDefaults`?

Comment: How can I confirm?

Comment: can you print this ` if let videoURL = videourl{` `videoURL`

Comment: and use `defaults.object(forKey:` instead of `defaults.value(forKey:`

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109512/cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-to-nsurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in method `func url(forKey defaultName: String) -> URL?` to retrieve `URL` as below,

```
   if let defaultsUrl = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "urlString") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: defaultsUrl)
    }
```